# Adding a primary key for Entity Framework to an existing column in a View based on a table where every column is Allow Null

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2008-r2, entity-framework-6

There are a lot of questions asking this but I can't seem to find one with the specific solution.

I have a 3rd party database where every field is set to allow null. One of the columns ("Code") is a unique string ID and it is distinct.

Using entity framework I'd like to add this table, by telling EF to treat the column "Code" as a primary key.

I've created a view but I am not sure where to go from here.

I've seen some solutions that involve adding an extra row number to use as the primary key but I would prefer to use "Code" if possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some playing around I found a read-only solution

In the view I modify the column to be:

`SELECT ISNULL(Code, -1) AS Code`

Specifying ISNULL allows EF to infer a primary key. It is not ideal as I would like it to be writable as well. You get the message:

> Error 6002: The table/view 'KittyCat.dbo.View_GetCatDetails' does not
>   have a primary key defined. The key has been inferred and the
>   definition was created as a read-only table/view.